# Tikz rectangle split widths

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to have a rectangle split in two and have the text width of one side be fixed instead of having the textwidth apply to both sides.

I have the following.

```
\tikzstyle{pblock} = [rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
                      rectangle split parts=2, very thick,draw=black!50, top
                      color=white,bottom color=black!20, align=center]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass the `text width` option directly to the `\nodepart` or you can set the

```
every <name> node part
```

style:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pblock/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
                      rectangle split parts=2, very thick,draw=black!50, top
                      color=white,bottom color=black!20, align=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[pblock]{\nodepart[text width=1cm]{one} Some first text
                \nodepart{two}Some other text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{/tikz/pblock/.append style = {every one node part/.style={text width=1cm}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[pblock]{\nodepart{one} Some first text
                \nodepart{two}Some other text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note you need to explicitly label the first part of the node for this to take effect.

See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/15925) for discussion of `\tikzset` vs. `\tikzstyle`